# Redis Get String appears to be slow

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

I have written some test code to retrieve 1000 strings from my `Redis cache`. Obviously it is getting the same string in this test but it was written to see how long it would take to get these 1000 items.

The test completes in `23 seconds`, so that is only around `43 strings per second` that seems quite slow.

I am running this locally against the `Redis` instance that is in `Azure`, so I’m assuming there will be some latency. Have I missed out something or is there a way to **reduce the time** to get these 1000 items?

In my production environment, there could be several thousand items that need to be retrieved.

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = @"testserver-rc.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=password,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,defaultDatabase=2";

        var redisClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(new NewtonsoftSerializer(), connectionString, 2);

        await TestGets(redisClient);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task TestGets(StackExchangeRedisCacheClient redisClient)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Running...");

        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            await redisClient.Database.StringGetAsync("test_T-0004");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{sw.Elapsed.Seconds} seconds");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

43 per second? That sounds pretty fast. That means including overhead and latency you are spending 23ms per query.

I think you want to parallelize the query.

Try replacing your query line with

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(I => redisClient.Database.StringGetAsync("test_T-0004"));
```

The problem is that you are latency bound. You are waiting for each request to complete before firing the next one off.

Comment: I tried running my code in the same region up in Azure and the code completed in around 2 seconds. It looks like the slowness I was seeing was down to the latency of running it on my local machine against the Redis cache in Azure.